# how to integrate google calendar in my app

Tags: javascript, php, frameworks, google-calendar-api

how to integrate #google #calendar in my app with full function ;mutli level management CRUD ect ;any suggestions ???
my app built in codeigniter (php framework)

there is other solutions easy to integrate in my application

Comment: I have no idea what multi level management CRUD is. Maybe add some more detail on what exactly you want to do

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/